# Cannot find my View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

All my Views are defined in a folder called "site_admin". But when I browse like this http://localhost:1234/site_admin/home/index. It gives me the following error

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /site_admin/home/index

It looks like its having problem finding the location of my View.  All my views should be inside the "site_admin" folder and should be accessible from there.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a controller named `site_adminController`?

Comment: No I don't. I just have a folder called site_admin

Answer (score 1):

Here is how routing works in MVC.  Default routing means you have a controller, like `UserController` and in that file there is a method, say `NewUser(...)`.  Then you also need a view folder named `User` and inside that a `NewUser.cshtml` file.  Now, if you to to `mysite.com/User/NewUser` that will first hit the User controller and look for the NewUser method.  Once that code is run it will look for the `NewUser.cshtml` file in the `Views/User` folder.

There are several way of overriding this default routing (routeconfig.cs, route attributes, etc) but that is the basics of how it all ties together.